# Make a Swift shared framework from C++ library

Tags: c++, ios, swift, cmake

I have a C++ shared library that cross-compiles for iOS, and I want to wrap it into a shared framework. The idea is that this library should run a server in a background thread while some Swift code connects to it.

It seems to me that a shared Framework is exactly what I want, but I can't figure out how to create it and the corresponding bridging header in order to be able to start the server from Swift.

Ideally, I would like to create it from CMake, following [this documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/prop_tgt/FRAMEWORK.html). However, it seems to me that my framework is completely ignored by the linker when I do that (I only did set `FRAMEWORK` and `FRAMEWORK_VERSION`, but I don't expect it to be the reason to have it ignored). I did something like this:

```
add_library(dynamicFramework SHARED
        dynamicFramework.c
)
set_target_properties(dynamicFramework PROPERTIES
    FRAMEWORK TRUE
    FRAMEWORK_VERSION C
)
```

I also tried to create a shared framework from Xcode and to add my C++ shared library in it, but the resulting framework binary is 50K when my C++ library was 30M, so I guess it doesn't really put it inside the Framework.

Is there any documentation about that that would show that it is even theoretically possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should inspect your framework binary with `nm`, e.g.: `nm MyLib.framework/MyLib`. It will show you all symbols contained in the framework. So you can check f something is missing.

You can create a shared lib with the following commands:

```
xcrun --sdk iphoneos clang -arch armv7 -arch arm64 -c -o hello_arm.o hello.c
xcrun --sdk iphonesimulator clang -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -c -o hello_x86.o hello.c
xcrun --sdk iphoneos ld -arch_multiple -arch arm64 -arch armv7 -dylib -dynamic -all_load -no_arch_warnings -dylib_install_name libhello_arm.so -ios_version_min 11.0 hello_arm.o -o libhello_x86.so
xcrun --sdk iphonesimulator ld -arch_multiple -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -dylib -dynamic -all_load -no_arch_warnings -dylib_install_name libhello_arm.so -ios_version_min 11.0 hello_arm.o -o libhello_arm.so
xcrun --sdk iphoneos lipo libhello_arm.so libhello_x86.so -create -output libhello.so
```

Now, you can create a shared framework from the shared lib by creating a directory structure according to [Bundle Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW26):

```
 MyFramework.framework/
     Headers/
     Base.lproj/
     de.lproj/
     en.lproj/
     Info.plist
     MyFramework
```

where `MyFramework` file is the shared lib created above.

Comment: All the symbols are there =/

Comment: Well, I've been trying that in the last 2 days. I've been trying to create a Framework from Xcode and also from CMake. The only one that seems to get embedded in the app is the one created by cmake, but then it doesn't find it at runtime (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48875082/cmake-generated-framework-image-not-found) =/. So I'm looking for some examples/documentation, because I'm kind of stuck right now.

Comment: I solved this problem by creating a static framework (with position independent code) via Makefile. Then I've created a Shared Framework Target in Xcode which includes the static library.

Comment: What do you mean, via Makefile? So you manually generate the framework? And isn't the point of the shared framework to allow for shared libs?

Comment: So you're saying that you gave up on doing a shared framework because of this error?

Comment: I've extended my post for creating a shared framework.

Comment: Seems like the framework structure is right, but the `rpath` set by xcode when I import it is wrong: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48875082/cmake-generated-framework-image-not-found