# iOS Framework: image not found

Tags: c++, ios, cmake

When trying to embed a shared Framework [generated from CMake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/prop_tgt/FRAMEWORK.html) into an Xcode iOS app, I encounter the following issue:

> dyld: Library not loaded: /Users/jones/Documents/project/build/ios/foo.framework/foo
>
> Referenced from: /var/Containers/Bundle/Application//myapp.app/myapp
>
> Reason: image not found

It seems like it has an incorrect "dylib id", but I am not sure what that means exactly. Note that my framework appears in the "Frameworks" folder of the app (the built "Product" that is installed on the phone).

Checking my app with `otool -L`, I see:

```
myapp:
    /Users/name/Documents/project/build/ios/foo.framework/foo
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
    /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
    ...
```

Which seems to show that the path to my framework is wrong in the app. But I can't seem to change it from Xcode.

On the [Apple dev forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/4687), somebody mentions changing DYLIB_INSTALL_NAME_BASE to `@rpath` from *Build Settings -> Dynamic Library Install Name Base*, but it doesn't solve my problem.

The linker log coming from Xcode looks like so (maybe easier to read [here](https://ptpb.pw/-MZN):

```
Ld /Users/jones/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-gngqigiisiapqjflqkjjadvdbneu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/myapp.app/myapp normal arm64
cd /Users/jones/Documents/project/ios-playground/myapp
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=11.2
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.2.sdk -L/Users/jones/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-gngqigiisiapqjflqkjjadvdbneu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/jones/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-gngqigiisiapqjflqkjjadvdbneu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/jones/Documents/project/ios-playground/myapp -F/Users/jones/Documents/project/ios-playground/myapp/Frameworks -filelist /Users/jones/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-gngqigiisiapqjflqkjjadvdbneu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/myapp.build/Debug-iphoneos/myapp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/myapp.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=11.2 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/jones/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-gngqigiisiapqjflqkjjadvdbneu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/myapp.build/Debug-iphoneos/myapp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/myapp_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -fembed-bitcode-marker -stdlib=libc++ -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/jones/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-gngqigiisiapqjflqkjjadvdbneu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/myapp.build/Debug-iphoneos/myapp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/myapp.swiftmodule -framework foo -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/jones/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-gngqigiisiapqjflqkjjadvdbneu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/myapp.build/Debug-iphoneos/myapp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/myapp_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/jones/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-gngqigiisiapqjflqkjjadvdbneu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/myapp.app/myapp
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have added your Framework to _Embedded Binaries_ in Xcode?

Comment: Yes but there it says "foo.framework _...in ../../project/build/ios_", so I suspect this path is set then instead of `@rpath/foo.framework/foo`.

Comment: The framework should be found in _Project Navigator_. If it is read, you should select it and change the Xcode reference to the correct location in _File Inspector_.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The framework shows in the _Project Navigator_. The "Full Path" is correct in the _File Inspector_. Interestingly, with `otool -L myapp` I don't see the link to the "Full Path" (i.e. the reference) but to the framework on my system (it should be @rpath/foo.framework/foo instead).

Comment: Could you add the linker output for the app to your post?

Comment: The path to the framework doesn't appear in the linking command. I am not sure what exactly sets it to `/Users/...` instead of `@rpath/...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually a way to set the "install_name_dir" in CMake:

```
set_target_properties(dynamicFramework PROPERTIES
    ...
    BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH TRUE
    INSTALL_NAME_DIR @rpath
)
```

Comment: Shouldn't the [`MACOS_RPATH`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/prop_tgt/MACOSX_RPATH.html?highlight=macosx_rpath#macosx-rpath) property set the `install_name` to `@rpath` without having to manually set it with `INSTALL_NAME_DIR` ?

Also, I believe `BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH` is only necessary to also have the `@rpath` in the build tree but is not necessary if using the framework/dylib from the install tree instead.